# Linking shared library mysql on ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, shared-libraries

I've been trying to create a small test application to start working with CMake and linking libraries.
The following is done:
- I installed the libmysqlcppconn5 library on Ubuntu (ie. it is now located in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn5.so, just the default installation)
- I created a small .cpp file with the following content

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
MYSQL *conn_ptr;
conn_ptr = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!conn_ptr) {
    std::cout << "mysql init failed\n";
    exit(1);
}
conn_ptr = mysql_real_connect (conn_ptr, "localhost", "root", "pw", "db", 0, NULL, 0);
if (conn_ptr) {
    std::cout << "connection success\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "connection failed\n";
}
mysql_close(conn_ptr);
```

How should I construct my CMakeLists.txt so it will use this shared library?

Comment: By using [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:find_library)?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
# Find and make sure the system have the header file
find_path(MYSQL_HEADER mysql/mysql.h)
if(MYSQL_HEADER STREQUAL "MYSQL_HEADER-NOTFOUND")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the mysql/mysql.h header file")
endif()

# Find and make sure the system have the library
find_library(MYSQL_LIBMYSQLCPPCONN5 mysqlcppconn5)
if(MYSQL_LIBMYSQLCPPCONN5 STREQUAL "MYSQL_LIBMYSQLCPPCONN5-NOTFOUND")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the mysqlcppconn5 library")
endif()

# Link the library to the target
target_link_libraries(your_target ${MYSQL_LIBMYSQLCPPCONN5})
```